# PHP can't figure out the right date format

Tags: php

I have data coming from mysql in the data type DATETIME which is in the format `2020-08-19 10:48:00`

However the input on my HTML form with the type "datetime-local" is `dd-mm-yyyy --:--`

So obviously if I try to set the inputs value to the fetched datetime, it doesn't work. I have a function that formats dates which is here:

```
function formatDate($date, $format){
  switch($format){
    //Sunday, 11th November 2018
    case 1: return date("l, jS F Y", strtotime($date));
      break;

        //11th November 2018
    case 2: return date("jS F Y", strtotime($date));
      break;

        //November 11th 2018
    case 3: return date("F jS Y", strtotime($date));
      break;

        //11-11-18
    case 4:return date("d-m-y", strtotime($date));
      break;

        //18-11-11
    case 5:return date("y-m-d", strtotime($date));
      break;

        //Sunday, 11th November 2018 @ 11:11
    case 6: return date("l, jS F Y @ H:i", strtotime($date));
      break;

        // 11:11
        case 7: return date("H:i a", strtotime($date));
            break;

        // 11/11/2020 11:11
        case 8: return date("d/m/Y @ H:i", strtotime($date));
            break;

        //20201111 for invoice pdf
      case 9:return date("Ymd", strtotime($date));
        break;

        // 11/11/2020 11:11
        case 10: return date("d/m/Y", strtotime($date));
            break;

        //Sunday, 11/11/2020 11:11
        case 11: return date("l, d/m/Y", strtotime($date));
            break;

        case 12: return (strtotime($date));
            break;

        case 13: return date("Y-m-d\TH:i", strtotime($date));
            break;

        case 14: return date("Y", strtotime($date));
            break;

        case 15: return date('%d-%m-%YT%H:%M', strtotime($date));
            break;
  }
}
```

But sadly I have tried all cases and case number 15 I added just now in an attempt. Can anyone tell me is there a better way or the actual correct format so I can implement it into my function

Comment: echo date('d-m-Y H:i:s', strtotime($date));

Comment: @FatFreddy No joy with that unfortunately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `datetime-local` input type expects the date to be in this format: `yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm` but you are supplying `%d-%m-%YT%H:%M` which is a sql date format. try using the following format:

```
return date('Y-m-d\TH:i', strtotime($date));
```

EDIT: Case 13 should do the trick